# How to set two items of same category at a time from json into android dropdown(Spinner) using adapter

Tags: android, json, adapter

Can anybody please explain me how to set two items of the same category at a time from json into android dropdown(Spinner) using adapter.

```
josn data:
{"categories":[{"id":"1","name":"Beverages"},{"id":"2","name":"Bread"},{"id":"3","name":"Cereals"},{"id":"4","name":"Cheese"},{"id":"5","name":"Citrus Fruits"}]}
```

Following is code I'am using to set only one item into spinner:

```
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: first parse your json object put it in arraylist Sort them according to your need and set custom adapter for spinner

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as "correct" if it helped you. From what I see, you have posed 6 questions on stack overflow, but you never accepted an answer as "correct" so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Firstly you need to parse your json for that json response convert into string
        ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
String response ={"categories":[{"id":"1","name":"Beverages"},{"id":"2","name":"Bread"},{"id":"3","name":"Cereals"},{"id":"4","name":"Cheese"},{"id":"5","name":"Citrus Fruits"}]}

JSONObject resJsonObj =new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray arrayData=resJsonObj.getJSONArray("categories");

for (int i = 0; i < arrayData.length(); i++) {
                    temp="";
                    JSONObject arrayObj = arrayData.getJSONObject(i);
                    temp=arrayObj.getString("name");
                    //temp=arrayObj.getString("id");
                    list.add(temp);
}
```

**This list pass in your array adapter as You need
you can also make a Array list generic type according to your bean class if you
want to get all element from json id**